# Versioning Room database

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

I may not be understanding `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`

When I change my Room version number, I want it to clear my table and repopulate as it did on first start up. But it does not call the "onCreate" in my callback which calls my populate method.
Instead the table only clears.

About my db:

it uses live data. The user can never alter the db. ID's are manually inserted in code as they are used as a foreign key to an online DB.

Is there a way for future migrations to just rebuild the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`, your `onCreate()` is not called as your DB is already created.

But you can rebuild the whole thing again using migration in the following way:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
.addMigrations(FROM_1_TO_2)
.build();

static final Migration FROM_1_TO_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(final SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("DELETE FROM `table_name`");    //this will empty table
        database.execSQL("YOUR_INSERTION_QUERY");    //insert in loop for multiple insertion
        }
    };
```

Using the above code, you can always clear and repopulate the table when updating DB version.